# Error with tex2docx function from reports R package

Tags: r, report, docx, tex

I'm trying to reproduce the example for `tex2docx` function in `reports`  `R` package and getting the following error.

```
DOC <- system.file("extdata/doc_library/apa6.qual_tex/doc.tex",
   package = "reports")
BIB <- system.file("extdata/docs/example.bib", package = "reports")
tex2docx(DOC, file.path(getwd(), "test.docx"), path = NULL, bib.loc = BIB)
```

**Error Message**

```
pandoc.exe: Error reading bibliography `C:/Users/Muhammad'
citeproc: the format of the bibliographic database could not be recognized
using the file extension.
docx file generated!
Warning message:
running command 'C:\Users\MUHAMM~1\AppData\Local\Pandoc\pandoc.exe -s C:/Users/Muhammad Yaseen/R/win-library/3.0/reports/extdata/doc_library/apa6.qual_tex/doc.tex -o C:/Users/Muhammad Yaseen/Documents/test.docx --bibliography=C:/Users/Muhammad Yaseen/R/win-library/3.0/reports/extdata/docs/example.bib' had status 23
```

I wonder how to get  `tex2docx` function in `reports`  `R` package working properly.

Comment: I strongly suspect you have a problem with spaces in your file path.  Don't know how to fix it other than testing in a file path without spaces, though.

Comment: You right @BenBolker, my file path has spaces. Any workaround.

Comment: you might be able to hack the package so that it sticks quotation marks around the relevant components of the command argument.

Comment: You might ping [@tyler-rinker](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1000343/tyler-rinker) to add `shQuote` inside of https://github.com/trinker/reports/blob/master/R/tex2docx.R

Comment: I'm actually unsure of how to do the `shQuote` but would greatly appreciate a pull request from someone who does if this will correct the problem.  Even if you corrected it for one I could complete the rest of the functions in that file.

Comment: @daroczig I know that forking and a pull request can be a pain so if you answered here and showed with how to properly implement the `shQuote` to the `tex2docx` I could add this to reports GitHub and MYaseen208 could download that version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the above comments, the error is caused by passing a filename/path including some spaces that are nor escaped, nor quoted. A workaround could be wrapping all file paths and names inside of `shQuote` before passing to the command line with `system`.

Code: https://github.com/trinker/reports/pull/31

---

Demo:

1. Loading package

   ```
   library(reports)
   ```
2. Creating  a dummy dir with a space in the name that would hold the `bib` file

   ```
   dir.create('foo bar')
   file.copy(system.file("extdata/docs/example.bib", package = "reports"), 'foo bar/example.bib')
   ```
3. Specifying the source and the copied `bib` file:

   ```
   DOC <- system.file("extdata/doc_library/apa6.qual_tex/doc.tex", package = "reports")
   BIB <- 'foo bar/example.bib'
   ```
4. Running the test:

   ```
   tex2docx(DOC, file.path(getwd(), "test2.docx"), path = NULL, bib.loc = BIB)
   ```

---

**Disclaimer:** I tried to test this pull request, but I could not setup an environment with all the needed tools to run `R CMD check` with vignettes and everything else after all in 5 mins (sorry but being on vacation right now and just enjoying the siesta after lunch), so please consider this pull request as "untested" -- although it *should* work.

Comment: I merged the pull request.  Many thanks.  I looked how and why you used `shQuote` and I think I get it.  Thanks again.  I built the package and tested the example and it works (though I have no spaces in the path so MYaseen208 will have to test).  The dev version can be downloaded via the instructions [here](https://github.com/trinker/reports).

Comment: I added this to the [NEWS](https://github.com/trinker/reports/blob/master/NEWS) file.  I used daroczig's actual name, however, MYaseen208 I used your stackoverflow handle.  If you'd like your name used please send me an email.

Comment: Thanks @daroczig and @Tyler Rinker for your help. Your provided code still gives error on my machine. The error message is `pandoc.exe: Error reading bibliography foo
citeproc: the format of the bibliographic database could not be recognized
using the file extension.
docx file generated!
Warning message:
running command 'C:\Users\MUHAMM~1\AppData\Local\Pandoc\pandoc.exe -s C:/Users/Muhammad Yaseen/R/win-library/3.0/reports/extdata/doc_library/apa6.qual_tex/doc.tex -o C:/Users/Muhammad Yaseen/Documents/test2.docx --bibliography=foo bar/example.bib' had status 23`.

Comment: What happens if you run `reports:::wheresPandoc()`?

Comment: @TylerRinker: Using `reports:::wheresPandoc()` gives me `pandoc 
"C:\\Users\\MUHAMM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Pandoc\\pandoc.exe"`.

Comment: When you type `tex2docx` in the command line check to make sure you get the same as: https://github.com/trinker/reports/blob/master/R/tex2docx.R including the `shQuote` added by daroczig.

Comment: @MYaseen208 the error msg shows that you are using a version of `tex2docx` that does not have the `shQuote` patch. Please install the most recent version of the package as described above by @Tyler Rinker **and** reload that (e.g.: `detach('package:reports', unload=T);library(reports)` *or* start a new R session.